# Motivation of Zariski–Van Kampen theorem

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, curves-and-surfaces, fundamental-group

The Zariski–Van Kampen theorem gives the presentation of the fundamental group of the complement of the plane curve of degree $d$. But what's the motivation of this theorem? More generally, why are people interested in the complement of a plane curve and its fundamental group?

Comment: Well, there are many reasons. For instance, the fundamental group of the complement provides information about the coverings of the plane branched over the curve.

Comment: To be more explicit, consider a sextic plane curve with six cusps. It is the branch locus of a triple cover if and only if the six cusps lie on a conic, and the two cases (cusps on a conic or not) can be distinguished by looking at the fundamental group of the complement. You might google "Zariski pair" for more information.

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi: it is the branched locus of a *non-Abelian* triple cover if and only if...

Comment: @MarcoGolla: right. I meant a generic (hence non-abelian) triple cover branched over the curve and with total ramification over the cusps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Francesco Polizzi mentioned, you might care about complex surfaces that you can obtain as covers of $\mathbb{CP}^2$ branched over curves. (All projective surfaces are obtained in this way, so maybe one should really care.)

If you don't want to think about surfaces, but stick to plane curves, here's another bit of motivation, perhaps. It's well-known that all non-singular curves of the same degrees are isotopic, meaning that they can be deformed one into another through non-singular curves. (In more algebro-geometric term, the corresponding stratum in the space of all curves of a fixed degree is connected.)

What happens if you go deeper into the stratification? Clearly each stratum only contains curves with a fixed combinatorics (meaning the same singularities and incidence relations). Does each possible configuration of singularities have a connected stratum? An invariant that can help you detect that is exactly the fundamental group of the complement. (The homology is not enough, as a relatively easy computation shows.) As Francesco Polizzi writes in his comment, Zariski gave the first (unexpected?? this is a good question for people who know the history better than me) examples of curves for which the answer is negative.

It turns out that the non-triviality of the fundamental group has some connection with the types and positions of the singularities. This was proved by Libgober in a series of papers on Alexander polynomials of complex curves. A good place to learn about this is perhaps Artal Bartolo, Cogolludo Agustin, and Tokunaga's excellent *A survey on Zariski pairs* (which contains a lot of information).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, could you please tell me a reference for "all non-singular curves of the same degrees are isotopic"?

Comment: For instance, this is Proposition 1.4.3 in Namba's *Geometry of projective algebraic curves*. That proposition shows that the set of non-singular curves in $\mathbb P^2$ is connected in the Euclidean topology, which allows you to deform the equation through non-singular polynomials, which in turn gives an isotopy (via Ehresmann's theorem).